# heap corruption detected by dlmalloc in Android

Tags: android, heap-corruption

My app crashed at the beginning. I had integrated [Splunk MINT](https://mint.splunk.com/) for crash, but it's not showing me any crash details in my dashboard.

My Logcat:

```
09-09 11:44:23.980 471-690/com.example.asus.connection A/libc: heap corruption detected by dlmalloc
09-09 11:44:23.980 471-690/com.example.asus.connection A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 690 (RenderThread)
```

Can anyone resolve this issue or provide exact details of this error?

**UPDATE:**

Whenever I install this app, it shows me this error and when I am re-installing it, it doesn't show any error. But when this error occurs and I'm trying to open the app, it shows this again and again, so I had to re-install to get rid of it. But whenever I update my code and install it, it shows this error.

Comment: Heap corruption is very hard to do in Java, short of a bug in the VM.  I'd look at any C/C++ code you're using.

Comment: Whenever i install this app it shows me this error and when i m re-installing it doesn't show any error but when this error occurs and m trying to open app it shows this again and again, so i had to re-install to get rid off it, but whenever i update my code and install it shows this error